# Creating a string text from values and indexes that meet condition

Tags: python, pandas, printing

I have the following dataset:

```
# creating dataset
dataset = pd.DataFrame()
dataset['name'] = ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Alex','Alex','Alex',
                   'Marie', 'Marie', 'Marie','Marie','Marie',
                   'Luke', 'Luke', 'Luke','Luke','Luke']
dataset['sales'] = [690,451,478,524,750,452,784,523,451,125,854,745,856,900,105]

dataset.info()
dataset.shape
```

I want to create and print a string that will let me know the sales reps whose mean sale's are above 500 units, in order to achieve this I first grouped the data and calculated the mean by name like so:

```
result_grouped=dataset.groupby(['name']).aggregate({'sales': 'mean'})
```

If I can use the following code to filter my target sales reps

```
print(list(result_grouped.index[(result_grouped['sales']>500)]))
result_grouped[(result_grouped['sales']>500)]
```

which gives:

```
['Alex', 'Luke']
        sales
name    
Alex    578.6
Luke    692.0
```

but my desired output will be something like so:

a printable string in the format:

"The reps in the target metrics are: `name1` with `mean1`, `name2` with `mean2`, ... , `namen` with `meann`"

**for this example my output will be:**

"The reps in the target metrics are Alex with 578.6, Luke with 692.0"

I am very new to Python (I come from an R environment and Python just seems to be very difficult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the pandas functions then use a list comp to unpack the list of tuples into a sentence.

```
result_grouped = (
    dataset
    .groupby(['name'])
    .aggregate({'sales': 'mean'})
    .query('sales.gt(500)')
    .reset_index()
    .to_records(index=False)
    .tolist()
)


print(f"The reps in the target metrics are {', '.join([f'{x[0]} with {x[1]}' for x in result_grouped])}")
```

Output:

```
The reps in the target metrics are Alex with 578.6, Luke with 692.0
```

Comment: Hey Jason thank you so much my man! What a great and simple solution,Im new to python what resourcers or books, or pages do you recommed to master pandas and data manipulation? Thank you so much

Comment: I liked 'Effective Pandas'  by Matt Harrison and 'Python For Data Analysis' by Wes McKinney.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
result_grouped=dataset.groupby(['name']).aggregate({'sales': 'mean'}).reset_index()
result_grouped=result_grouped[(result_grouped['sales']>500)]

result_grouped['text']=result_grouped['name'] + ' with ' + result_grouped['sales'].astype(str)
listt=', '.join(result_grouped['text'].to_list())
final="The reps in the target metrics are {}".format(listt)

print(final)
'''
The reps in the target metrics are Alex with 578.6, Luke with 692.0
'''
```